# Django: prepopulate formset

Tags: django, formset

I have a formset, but I can't figure out how to prepopulate it with data from the database.

Truth be told, I have a model Library and a model Book that has a foreign key to Library. I want someone to be able to edit all of the book in one library (at a time).

html

```
        {{ book_form.management_form }}
        {% for form in book_form.forms %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
        {% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
class LibraryUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
model      = Library
form_class = LibraryChangeForm
template_name = 'libraries/library_update.html'

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(LibraryUpdateView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.request.POST:
        context['book_form'] = BookFormSet(self.request.POST)
    else:
        context['book_form'] = BookFormSet()
    return context
```

forms

```
class LibraryChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        exclude = ['updated']

BookFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Library, Book, exclude = () )
```

How do I prepopulate the html page to show the data in the formset. In my loop there are 3 loops for `{{form.as_p}}`. When I run `print(BookFormsSet())` I see the following

```
<input type="hidden" name="perdateinfo_set-TOTAL_FORMS" value="3"...
```

So it looks like it is generating three blank forms.

When I run `print(PerDateInfoFormSet(qs,qs2))` for `qs = Library.objects.filter(library_id='slkdfj') and qs2=Book.objects.filter(library_id='slkdfj')` It tells me `too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Can I pass in a query set? I imagine that I will be passing in a qs.first() to get the library and then multiple (qs2) query sets to get all of the books in the  library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass instance argument to the formset:

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(LibraryUpdateView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.request.POST:
        context['book_form'] = BookFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
    else:
        context['book_form'] = BookFormSet(instance=self.object)
    return context
```

Comment: So, I ended up getting this error: Cannot query "zd4zjgla0j": Must be "Library" instance, where 'zd4zjgla0j' is a book instance. Instead of self.instance I put a queryset to the library instance for that book and it worked. Thank you!